# Undefined data from content script in background

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to pass data from **content script**:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({key: "abc", data: results}, function(response){});
```

And then recieve it in **background**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.key == "abc") {
        var a = message.data;
        var b = message.data.innerText;
        for (var i = 0; i < message.data.length; i++) {
            var c = a[i].innerText;
        }
```

I get `undefined` in all variables. And all i want to do is to pass collection that i got from page to background and process it there. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({key: "abc", data: results}, function(response){});
```

`text` vs `results`

But even then, you can't pass DOM nodes around, because they are not JSON-serializable.

You need to extract the information on the content script side and pass only what you need (i.e. if you need only `innerText`, pass that and not the node)